# Is a norm closed set(in the topology induced by the norm) weakly closed?

Tags: functional-analysis

My attempt:Yes because since $T_{\text{Norm}} \supset T_{\text{Weak}} \implies  T_{\text{Norm}}^{C} \subset T_{\text{Weak}}^C$ Right? Or have I got something wrong here?

This first set inclusion holds because weak topology is defined as the topology which makes all the functionals on the dual space continuous which are already continuous by definition in the norm topology

Comment: Presumably: No!! Why then study von Neumann algebras?

Comment: @Freeze_S I hadn't heard of von Neumann Algebras.Do you study TMP at LMU?

Comment: I have to think about von Neumann algebras first. Will tell you later. But for now: They are important for the functional calculus of possibly unbounded normal operators.

Comment: Ah and yes I do. :) You too?

Comment: By the way the answer is certainly 'no'. Suppose a net is weakly Cauchy. Then it may not be strongly Cauchy. An example provides Riemann-Lebesgue.

Comment: @Freeze_S I am in the same department. I study Wirtchaftsmathematik.

Comment: Aaaahh nice. :D What's your topic?

Comment: I am an double degree exchange student from India taking my first course on analysis(functional analysis 1 ) which is a bit overwhelming because i haven't taken any formal math course in analysis and hence the stupid questions.

Comment: There's no stupid questions only stupid answers(ers). ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is no. At the very least, it is not true that the set of closed sets is the complement of the set of open sets. Instead, the closed sets are the complements of the open sets, which is different. Indeed, adding open sets also adds closed sets!

The example I have in mind is $X=L^2([0,\pi])$, where $\sin(nx)$ is a sequence which is contained on a sphere and converges weakly to zero, which is not on the sphere. Thus I think that the sphere cannot be weakly closed, but it is certainly strongly closed (the norm is strongly continuous and singletons are closed in $\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: A bit simpler would be to take the set of standard unit vectors in $\ell_2$. This set is norm closed and has $0$ as a weak limit point.

Comment: @Ian Thank you Ian. I was actually trying to prove that a norm closed convex bounded subset of a compact set in a reflexive Banach space is compact. in the weak topology And I thought probably convexity was not required if I could just show that norm closed implies weak closed and use the lemma that closed subsets of compact sets are compact

Answer (score 2):

No.  The closed sets are the complements of the open sets.  If every norm closed set was weakly closed, every norm open set would be weakly open, and the two topologies would be the same.